# password_verify() against MySQL doesn't work

Tags: php, password-hash

I store the password, get through a form, into MySQL database via PDO, after having hashed it with password_hash()
(VARCHAR(512) field)

```
$options = array(
    'cost' => 12
);
$password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
```

Suppose that

```
$pass = "123Azerty";
//and the hash is
$hash = "$2y$12$TzpGzy1cKM81pkEr/Mn0SOVA4wn0lr.7PnKFg4SU9Hto0EUiGGRMe";
```

When I get the password from the database and I verify it with password_verify() it returns always false

```
...
...
$returnedPWD = $row['password'];
if (password_verify($pass,$returnedPWD)){
    echo "TRUE";
} else {
    echo "FALSE";
}
...
...
```

At this point, I tried to do it "manually" in this way

```
$pass = "123Azerty";
$hash = "$2y$12$TzpGzy1cKM81pkEr/Mn0SOVA4wn0lr.7PnKFg4SU9Hto0EUiGGRMe";
if (password_verify($pass,$hash )){
    echo "TRUE";
} else {
    echo "FALSE";
}
```

And it always returned FALSE

BUT

when I changed

```
$hash = "$2y$12$TzpGzy1cKM81pkEr/Mn0SOVA4wn0lr.7PnKFg4SU9Hto0EUiGGRMe";
// into
$hash = '$2y$12$TzpGzy1cKM81pkEr/Mn0SOVA4wn0lr.7PnKFg4SU9Hto0EUiGGRMe';
```

it worked. Because the hash enclosed in single quotes, is not parsable.
On my understanding, it means that the hash taken from database, it is interpreted as parsable (double totes) than it doesn't work at all

then I tried to enclose the string out the db int strval():

```
...
...
$returnedPWD = strval($row['password']);
if (password_verify($pass,$returnedPWD)){
    echo "TRUE";
} else {
    echo "FALSE";
}
...
...
```

But it returns always FALSE
reading all the posts related the not functioning of password_verify(), I didn't come up to any valid solution, for me.

Please is there a way to make it work?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT 1**

I did try with other settings as PASSWORD_DEFAULT but  no changes.
I also tried to base64 encode it upfront database storage, then decode it. But nothing changed

**EDIT 2**

I store the data using PDO with parameters

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)";

 $params = array(
            ':username' => "$username",
            ':password' => "$password" // hashed one
        );
```

**EDIT 3**

Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `enabled` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;


$username = trim($_POST["username"];
$password = trim($_POST["password"];

// Query to insert data
 $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (username, password, enabled) VALUES (:username, :password, 1)";

// The very original setup I did use and didn't work out
$param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); 

// Bind parameters
$params = array(
     ':username' => "$username",
     ':password' => "$param_password"
);
...
...
// insert into db
$sth = $sql->prepare($query);

// Call MySQL
try {
    $sth->execute($params); // Execute the Query
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $mysql_error = 'MySQL connection failed: ' . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
...
...
```

and here the fundamental lines on how I read from database

```
...
...
$username_login = trim($_POST["username"]);
$password_login = trim($_POST["password"]);
...
...   
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username = :username";
$params = array(
    ':username' => $username_login
);   

$sth = $sql->prepare($query);

try{
    $sth->execute($params);
} catch (PDOException $e)  {
    $mysql_error = 'MySQL connection failed: ' . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        global $$key;
        $$key = $value;
    }
}
...
...

if (password_verify($password_login, $password) and $enabled == 1){
    // Password is correct, so start a new session
    session_start();

    // Store data in session variables
    $_SESSION["logged"] = true;
    $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
    $_SESSION["uname"] = $username_login_;                            

    // Redirect user to welcome page
    header("location: index.php");

} else {
    // Display an error message if password is not valid
    $password_login__err = "The password you entered was not valid. Or you are not enabled";
}
...
...
```

Comment: Have you checked in your DB what is actually stored? How do you insert the hash into DB, can you show us that code too? If it is parsed somewhere it looks like an SQL injection. What is your column collation? What is your connection charset?

Comment: That's not entirely correct. The string from the database will be treated as a string, and the content inside it will not be evaluated. Your inserted data is possibly altered in some fashon.

Comment: What is  `var_dump($returnedPWD);`?

Comment: And what do you do to `$password` before passing it to `password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);`?

Comment: @Qirel I tried also to serialze it, and also to encode base64 before to store it.
I get the same result

Comment: Why..? Don't do anything to it, just put the password straight into `password_hash()`, then store that.

Comment: @qirel it's what I did till the desperation :-/ then i started to encode it to see if I could solve anything ...

Comment: It's quite simple: The column in the DB table must be at least 60 characters length. Insert `password_hash('the_password', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);` into the password column --- don't escape it, don't trim it, don't do anything - just the exact password the user submitted. Then when you fetch that, run it through as the second parameter to `password_verify('the_password', $hashedFromDB)`

Comment: @Qirel as I said: the column is 512 characters VARCHAR.
I did try also with PASSWORD_DEFAULT I get the same issue.
I have not clue what to do more£P.S. Var_dump() returns string(60)

Comment: Follow the flow as described in my previous comment. Keep in mind that any passwords you stored can be incorrect since you modified the data. So, clear out the data - and run it through the flow as described above. ;-)

Comment: @Qirel what you suggests, it's exactly what I did before to try something else. It doesn't work. I edited my message adding some more info

Comment: You must be doing *something* different. The flow I suggested above is how you do it, and if that's not working, you're doing something else that interferes.

Comment: Your manual fails, because `"$2y$12..."` interpolates as variables, that's why it works with single quotes

Comment: @justinas and how to solve it retrieving the hash that contains that $2y$12 or just $2y$ (with PASSOWRD_DEFAULT) from database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not work because of `"$password "` - it has space at the end. It should be:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)";

$params = array(
        ':username' => $username,
        ':password' => $password, // hashed one
    );
```

---

Your manual test does not work because

```
$hash = "$2y$12$TzpGzy1cKM81pkEr/Mn0SOVA4wn0lr.7PnKFg4SU9Hto0EUiGGRMe";
```

has double quotes and it interpolates `$2y`, `$12` and `$Tz...` as variables that leads to empty string. That's why single quotes works.

---

From your provided information I constructed sample code that does work: [Check here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/187a7dbbdcac5c5393d9b978ff8b69046aa8a497)

Comment: no sorry, this was my mistake while i posted here. There  is not any space on the code (I go to correct it here as well)

Comment: about the "$2y" etc: it has also into the variable out the database

Comment: @TormyVanCool There is no problem if you use it in DB, it's problem when you write it manually in code in double quotes. As long as it stays in variables, there is no this interpolation

Comment: the way you made the working code, is also a way I made ti one, just to test it. And indeed with the code so made: it works.
But when I go to retrieve from database, it doesn't. And the string is correct. Hence I asked if is there anything that can create this issue with DB.
I tried several  ways but it returns always: false

Comment: @TormyVanCool Maybe your database encode is wrong? Can you do `$manuallyWrittenHash === $row['password']`? Maybe database field is too short and end of hash just cuts off?

Comment: as I said in the begin of the post, the field is varchar(512)

Comment: @TormyVanCool Can you share your table structure and full code how you write to database and how you retrieve it? There is somewhere some flaw that you did not mentsion.

Comment: I edited and added how I write data into it and the structure of the table.
TO read it it's in the same way fetching the content

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196326/discussion-between-justinas-and-tormy-van-cool).